# How do I write a LINQ to SQL statement with a custom function that needs the compare the current item context to a passed in value?

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql, lambda

I want to see if a record exists in DB.  I'm checking for null/whitespace and then doing a string compare everywhere and I want to put in a function so I don't have to write the same code over and over.

Here's what the code looks like for each thing I'm comparing to...

```
return Db.AttributeNames.FirstOrDefault(an =>
    (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(an.Name) &&
    string.Compare(attributeName.Name, an.Name, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == 0) &&
    (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(an.Namspace) &&
    string.Compare(attributeName.Namespace, an.Namspace, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == 0));
```

I have tried something like this...it obviously isn't right.

```
public Class1 Get(string url)
{
    return Db.Class1s.FirstOrDefault(f => Equal<Class1>(f.Value, url));
}
public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> Equal<T>(string input, string url)
{
    return a => input == url; // just to test for now, I need to add null/ws check and do compare
}
```

I know, I know. I have no idea what I'm doing..but I would appreciate some help!

Comment: Do you always compare AttributeNames or other entities also? And always Name and AttributeName?

Comment: No, just need a generic function to compare strings

Answer (score 1):

You will probably need to create an extension method:

```
 public static class MyExtensions
 {
    public static bool UrlEqual(this Class1s obj, string url)
    {
         return obj.Value == url;
    }
 }
```

Then you can make the following call:

```
 return Db.Class1s.FirstOrDefault(f => f.UrlEqual(url));
```